# Boost, posix time from string issues

Tags: c++

I need to use the function boost::posix_time::time_from_string(string) but it doesn't work ...

With a very simple exemple :

#### My code (main.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    using namespace boost::posix_time;
    cout << "Getting t1" << endl;
    ptime t1 = microsec_clock::universal_time();
    cout << "Getting t1 OK" << endl;

    cout << "Getting t2" << endl;
    ptime t2 = time_from_string(to_iso_string(t1));
    cout << "Getting t2 OK" << endl;
}
```

#### Output

```
Getting t1
Getting t1 OK
Getting t2
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_lexical_cast> >'
  what():  bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

#### My Cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(sandbox)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
find_package(Boost 1.45.0 COMPONENTS date_time)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(sandbox main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(sandbox ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two functions to get `ptime` from string, `ptime time_from_string(std::string)` and `ptime from_iso_string(std::string)`. You want to get `ptime` from string returned by `to_iso_string` so should use the second:

```
cout << "Getting t2" << endl;
ptime t2 = from_iso_string(to_iso_string(t1));
cout << "Getting t2 OK" << endl; // printed
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `from_iso_string` instead of `time_from_string`

```
ptime t2 = from_iso_string(to_iso_string(t1));
```